# EntityManager and two DAO with PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED

Tags: spring, jpa, dao, entitymanager

I have a problem with my entity manager in my application. I have two DAO clasess like this:

```
@Repository
public abstract class DaoA 
{
    protected ClassA persistentClass;

    @PersistenceContext(name="my.persistence", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
    -------------- some typical action for DAO --------------
}
```

Second DAO is for ClassB and looks similar to DaoA. The rest of things are done for me by the Spring framework.

When I'm debugging the application I recognize that both DAO objects have different instances of EntityManager. In the result my two different DAOs are connected with different PersistenceContext.

Question is if this is correct behaviour or not? I would like to have the same PersistenceContext for all my DAO classes. Please give me a hint if this is possible and if I understood the JPA correctly?

Regards Hsd

Answer (score 1):

It's a correct behaviour of `EXTENDED` persistence context, therefore you don't need it to be `EXTENDED` in this case.

In most cases you need a `TRANSACTIONAL` persistence context, that is the default mode when `type` is omitted:

```
@PersistenceContext(name="my.persistence")
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

In this mode persistence context is associated with the transaction, so that all DAOs will share the same persistence context when working inside the same transaction. I guess it's what you need.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. Does this mean that it is not possible to have only ONE PersistenceContext instance  for many DAO instances?

Comment: Only ona additional question. Is this possible to have PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED which it is share over all my DAOs?

Comment: @hsd: The purpose of `EXTENDED` persistence context is to create a persistnce context associated with the particular instance of the stateful object. DAOs are usually stateless. If you understand it and actually have a stateful object that calls methods of your DAOs, you can inject `EXTENDED` context into it and pass it to DAO methods as a parameter.